# Is it possible to get Hdfs image/video file metadata using Exiftool

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, exiftool

`exiftool image.jpg` Gives me metadata of image file on linux. I am trying to fetch HDFS image file metadata like `exiftool hdfs://10.253.11.10:8020/tmp/user/vid2.avi`.

But getting error like `File not found:`. How to read metadata of HDFS file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pipe:

```
hdfs dfs -cat hdfs://10.253.11.10:8020/tmp/user/vid2.avi | exiftool -
```

Comment: facha has the correct answer.  Exiftool isn't able to read files over a network.

Comment: exiftool - gives me standard output & not all attributes like createdDate,modifiedDate.Is there any way to include that in output of above command

Comment: Are you sure those tags are in the file?  By default, exiftool will print out all the tags it finds.  Unless you mean the the file system tags like FileModifyDate and FileCreateDate.  Exiftool won't have access to those over a network.  You might look into mounting hdfs as a drive.  A google search pull up [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) as an option to do that.